# Реализация глобальных настроек игры

Tags: c#, unity3d

Для шашечного приложения я хочу реализовать глобальные настройки, которые сохраняются с выходом из игры: пользовательские цвета полей доски, цвета шашек, скорость передвижения шашек, громкость музыки и т.п.

Эти характеристики могут быть изменен из разных мест в игре (главное меню, основные настройки, настройки партии...)

Вопрос: как это правильно реализовать?

У меня есть 2 варианта:

1. Сделать **статичный класс** для настроек и обращаться к нему напрямую, а при выходе из игры сериализовать настройки в файл.

```
public static class GlobalSettings
{
    public static float CheckerJumpTime;
    public static Color SquareWhiteColor;
    public static Color SquareBlackColor;
    ...
}
```

2. Сделать настройки **ScriptableObject** и *отдельный класс* для управления настройками. Так можно будет иметь несколько экземпляров настроек (несколько по умолчанию, несколько пользовательских) и выбирать/менять нужные по необходимости. Но в таком случае класс для управления настройками у меня неизбежно сводится к Singleton.

```
public class GlobalSettings : ScriptableObject
{
    public float CheckerJumpTime = 0.2f;
    public Color SquareWhiteColor = new Color(0.96f, 0.89f, 0.82f);
    public Color SquareBlackColor = new Color(0.70f, 0.39f, 0.24f);
    // ...
}


public class GlobalSettingsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GlobalSettings[] _settings; // Экземпляры настроек

    private int _currentSettingsIndex = 0; // Индекс используемых сейчас настроек

    private static GlobalSettingsManager _instance; // Синглтончик :(

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance != null)
            Destroy(gameObject);
        _instance = FindObjectOfType<GlobalSettingsManager>();
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}
```

В первом случае меня пугает статика, а во втором Singleton. Существует ли более "гибкий" вариант?

Comment: Со статикой понятно, а синглтон чем пугает? И в чем именно вам не хватает "гибкости"?

Comment: Есть проще вариант для таких настроек. Создать атрибут, помечать им поля/свойства, которые нужно сохранять. Через рефлексию найти эти поля и сохранить/загрузить настройки. Не нужно будет никаких глобальных настроек, все будет находиться там где должно, для пресетов настроек создавать json файл и в нем все менять.

Comment: @aepot Уж очень часто ругаются на синглтон, а у меня пока не хватает опыта понять, когда он действительно излишен, а когда нужен и правилен. Поэтому стараюсь по возможности избегать:)

Comment: Ничего страшного в синглтонах нет, частенько их просто реализуют через зад. У вас вроде выглядит нормально. Синглтон это рациональная замена статике, никакой магии здесь нет.

Comment: А зачем инициализировать синглтон поиском? Разве текущий класс где реализовывается не является целью? `_instance = this` я всячески избегаю любого Find метода движка, очень он затратный

Comment: @AlemkhanUtepkaliev Сейчас не могу проверить, но думаю, так делать нельзя, иначе бы я также сделал:) про затратность спору нет, но в любом случае этот Find сработает 1 раз за все время игры.

Comment: Может я чего-то не знаю, но я всегда передаю ссылку на текущий класс через `this`, и я не находил явных проблем

Comment: @AlemkhanUtepkaliev Написал синглтон на C# (без юнити). Жалуется сразу: `Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer`

Comment: Как и пишет IDE нельзя в static методе использовать this, конструкция `_instance = this` в юнити работает прекрасно из за того что там инициализация в не статических методах, в статике и там тоже не получиться, для C# проекта это нужно будет реализовывать вне static метода как и пишет IDE вот демонстрация - https://yadi.sk/d/q76YwC_9vX01HA, работает прекрасно также

Answer (score 4):

На тему `singleton` и статика, `singleton` и есть статика. От того что там не каждое поле `static` (таких классов не должно существовать) и сам класс не статический, а только одно поле, не меняет того факта что весь доступ через статику.

Я бы порекомендовал все параметры настроек хранить в одной/нескольких структуре, которую легко сохранять/загружать как `json` в `playerprefs`. Готовые присеты настроек могут храниться в `scriptableobject` (`so`) который как handler этой структуры.

А непосредственно `so` или `singleton` содержащая настройки выполняет роль прокладки, которая грузит параметры в начале и автоматически/по команде сохраняет при изменении.

`So` это конечно замечательно, но прокидывать на него ссылку везде и ограничевать себя только связями с monobehaviour не целесообразно, тот случай когда `singleton` все же практичнее. Не monobeh или so, класический c# `singleton`.

П.с. `so` это не способ сохранения, он сериализуется только в редакторе и залит цементом в билде.